# How to get all public calendar of specific user?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm wondering how can I retrieve all shared Google Calendar of a specific user. I've a `Service Account`, so I don't need to ask the user permission.

Actually I'm wring a small application in c#. When I need to add an event for a specific user email, I simple do:

```
Event myEvent = new Event
{
     Summary = "Appointment"
     Location = "Somewhere",
     ...
     Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>() 
     {
          new EventAttendee() { Email = "foo@gmail.com"}
     }
};
```

So how you can see I pass the `email` of the user in the `Attendees` property. This allow me to put the appointment in the main calendar of a specific user.

What I want to know is: How can I achieve the same for the shared `Google Calendar`? In this way, the application show to the user email, a list of him public calendar, select one, and I can put the event to the specified email and calendar.

I tried to do something like this:

```
 var calendars = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;

 foreach (CalendarListEntry entry in calendars)
 {
     entry.Summary;
 }
```

but `calendars` return `Count = 0`, 'cause I don't have specified any email, so I suppose that the API try to access to my API email, right? How can I tell to the API the email of the user to take a list of calendar by the method `CalendarList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service accounts aren't you its a dummy account.  You have two options you can grant the service account access (just share it) to a calendar you create on your own Google Calendar account then it will be able to [insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) into that calendar or you can create a new calendar on the service accounts google calendar account.

Either way you will be able to create a new event and add people to it.  Then when you want to add someone you use [events.instert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and set notify on.  The user will get an email and be able to add it to there own personal Google calendar.

Skip calendar.list which was recommended in another answer. IMO calendar list is useless its just the little list of calendars you have access to in the web view its the list on the bottom left.   If you really want to use it you will have to use calendar.list.insert to add the calendar you create above to add it to the service accounts calendar list.  But like i said i dont see the point of calendar list for service accounts.

Comment: Very interesting answer, the goal of my app is show the user calendars so the user can select him private calendario and put the service on it. But I guess that I need to use OAuth and ask him the permission in order to use my app.

Comment: Yup if you need to access the users calendar then you are going to have to use Oauth2.  Then you can add them to the service account after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Calendar API to find and view public calendar events. You can also access and modify private calendars and events on those calendars if you're authorized.

To know how to do it and see sample codes, you may follow instructions of your preferred quickstart guides given in [Get Started with the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview#apis_explorer).

And, to take a list of calendar by [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#request), after you enable OAuth 2.0 authorization, you may send an HTTP Request with additional parameters with the sample format:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList`

Comment: so I guess I need to ask the authorization to the user before get a list of him calendars, right? I actually have a Service Account, and I'm able to see only the shared calendar with my Service Account. But if I understood correctly, also if the user specify him calendar id, I can't add event to him calendar without him authorization. This is how it works, do you agree?

Comment: No you cant add an event to a calendar just with the calendar Id unless its been set to public.